ExtJS 3.4 Desktop Interface Skin
Are there consultants or companies out there who can explain how, or recommend someone who can help solve this UI issue on an older version of ExtJS3.4.
This is our existing UI on an Ext JS 3.4 project. Can this be themed/styled to look more like Windows 11 and more modern, more whitespace and flat elements. An icon redesign is already underway,

Anyone think its possible to do with all those sprites and UI slices and component CSS?

There are two possible ways to do so:

Go over all x- css classes to get your result

Later Version OR Themer



Use a standard theme from a later version of ExtJS OR Use Themer with a later version
Use the build css from the first step as a starting point, as most components base structure did not change that much. Do fine-tuning on that one.


Work with a freelancer, as you are currently asking them ;)

About the slices: It is all handled by the build tools
